# How to get an element's height

Tags: birt

I would like to know how can I get an element's **computed (real)** height.

More specifically I have two tables beneath. I need to set height of the second one according to the height of the first one. How can I get the first table height?

I've tried to add script to the first table *onCreate* to get its height:

```
importPackage(Packages.java.lang);
if (this.height == null) {
    System.out.println("null");
} else {
    System.out.println(this.height);
}
```

but *this.height* returns *null* until I manually set a value to the table's height property in the report design. But I need the real computed height, that depends on row count.

Comment: have you tried to add the script to `onRender` instead?

Comment: What is your output format?  You are asking for a table height, and for the most part, I don't think these are known at report run time.  Unless you have some very specific design criteria, the table height is un-knowable until the report has been created and all the wraps have increased the cell height. Most (all?) of this occurs to late to influence the second table even if you could capture it.

Answer (score 2):

The comment by James Jenkins is the correct answer: It is just impossible.

However, what are you trying to achieve anyway?

If jou just want a nice frame drawn around it, you could wrap the two tables in a 2x1 grid.

Comment: I was afraid of it's not possible. I have two tables. The first one is dynamic and the second one is static (it's a grid in fact). And I need to set height of the second one to have both tables on one page. My output is a PDF.